# What did Skylab 1 carry in its nosecone?

Tags: skylab, nosecone

Skylab 1 was the uncrewed Saturn V flight that launched the space station.  The workshop itself was adapted from the Saturn's third stage.  As this was an uncrewed flight, there was no need for a command module, service module, lunar module, or launch escape system.

For aerodynamic purposes, a nosecone was needed to cover the blunt end of the third stage.  **Was there any equipment inside the nosecone, or between it and the third stage?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this webpage](http://what-when-how.com/space-science-and-technology/skylab/), under the payload shroud were the airlock, the multiple docking adapter, and the Apollo telescope mount.  The latter was folded in front of them but swung to the side on orbit entry.  The Saturn Instrumentation Unit (I.U.) was also above the third stage.

[image: Skylab-1 configuration]

Comment: I love the George Mueller sketch on that page, big "8 year old future rocket scientist" energy.